# I'm new to angular 5 and getting this error: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:'employee-list' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm new to Angular 5 and  watching a tutorial and the instructor made two components then add their tags to the app.component.html

it gives me this error in console:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'employee-list' is not a known element:
1. If 'employee-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'employee-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
</div>
```

the video for this in the tutorial:
https://www.udemy.com/angular-mastering-the-basics/learn/v4/t/lecture/10121074?start=30

here is my code:
app.component.html:

```html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  
</div>

<employee-list></employee-list>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from './employee-list/employee-list.component';
import { EmployeeDetailComponent } from './employee-detail/employee-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeeListComponent,
    EmployeeDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

employee-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

  public employees;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

employee-list.component.html:

```
<p>
  employee-detail works!
</p>
```

I don't understand what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Can we see the code and template of `EmployeeListComponent`?

Comment: I edit it now with EmployeeListComponent @ConnorsFan

Comment: Try `<app-employee-list></app-employee-list>`. You should use the selector defined in the component code.

Comment: great it works :D thanks alot.but how it works with the instructor and he write as above in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, by default Angular adds `app` as a prefix. So you should use `<app-employee-list></app-employee-list>`. Additionally, if you are not sure, have a look at component's selector. In your case this is your selector. `selector: 'app-employee-list',`. Fell free to change it, but it is recommended naming.

Comment: I have used <add-employee-list></app-employee-list> in app.component.html . But i am getting same error.
Error: node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:5998:22 - error NG1010: Value

Error: src/app/app.component.html:8:1 - error NG8001: 'app-employee-list' is not a known element:        
1. If 'app-employee-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-employee-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

error facing long time. Using Angular16

Answer (score 1):

Use `<app-employee-list></app-employee-list>` instead. The name of the tag/selector is specified in `employee-list.component.ts`:

```
...
 selector: 'app-employee-list'
...
```